# Converting SQL to LINQ formatting where clause

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

```
 Qry = "select childID,ChildEmail,ChildUserID, ChildPassword from ChildProfile ";
 Qry = Qry + " where ucase(ChildFName) = '" 
           + Strings.UCase(Strings.Trim(Txtname.Text)) 
           + "' and ucase(childlname) = '" 
           + Strings.UCase(Strings.Trim(txtSurName.Text)) 
           + "' and childmobile = '" 
           + Strings.Trim(txtMobile.Text) + "'";
```

How do we convert this query into LINQ

```
List<PatientDTO> lstChildProf = objService.GetAllPatient();
    lstChildProf = new List<PatientDTO>(
        from l in lstChildProf where 
        );
```

Don't know how to write the where clause here

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
List<PatientDTO> lstChildProf = objService.GetAllPatient()
    .Where( l => l.ChildFName == Strings.UCase(Strings.Trim(Txtname.Text))
            && l.ChildName == Strings.UCase(Strings.Trim(txtSurName.Text)) 
            && l.chiuldMob == Strings.Trim(txtMobile.Text))
    .ToList<PatientDTO>();
```

Comment: Error 14 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ChildVaccination.PatientDTO>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ChildVaccination.PatientDTO>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Either change `List<PatientDTO>` to `IEnumerable<PatientDTO>` or put a `ToList()` onto the end of that code.

Comment: @vini, I don't know what type the `GetAllPatient()` method returns, but you can put `.ToList<PatientDTO>()` in the end of the it as [Arran suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297580/converting-sql-to-linq-formatting-where-clause/12297732#comment16498334_12297732)